# Oracle SQL SELECT max values out of multiple groups

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

The tables involved:

```
    TEAM
IDTEAM(NUMBER)(pk)
NAME(VARCHAR(30))
LEVEL(VARCHAR(30))
DATE_CONSTI(DATE)
CITY(VARCHAR(30))

     PLAYER
IDPLAYER(NUMBER)(pk)
IDTEAM(NUMBER)(fk)
NAME(VARCHAR(30))
ADDRESS(VARCHAR(30))
CITY(VARCHAR(30))
ID(VARCHAR(9))
LEVEL(VARCHAR(30))
DATE_BIRTH(DATE)

      EVENT
IDEVENT(NUMBER(pk)
IDGAME(NUMBER)
IDPLAYER(NUMBER)(fk)
MINUTE(NUMBER)
TYPE_EVENT(VARCHAR(30))
COMMENTARY(VARCHAR90))
```

The goal is to select, for each TEAM, the PLAYER with the most goals (entries in EVENT with TYPE_EVENT='GOAL' that refer to that PLAYER), displaying the TEAM name and PLAYER name. Like so:

`TEAM   |   PLAYER`

```
 LIONS     |     JOHN
 CROWS     |     MARIAH
```

I've been trying to solve it for about a day and I don't think I've gotten close.

This is an exam question meant to be solved on paper, and there are no indications as to score ties or other conflicts

Comment: Hi Gilberto, please provide data sample, it will be easier to work with.  And please in text format. Welcome to SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are *lots* of ways to write something like this.  Since you're talking about soccer goals, I'm going to assume that your table doesn't have millions of rows in it and that simple to understand is more important than efficience.

Start with this..

```
select team.name team_name, 
       player.name player_name,
       count(*) number_of_goals
from       team
inner join player on player.idteam = team.idteam
inner join event on event.idplayer = player.idplayer
where event.type_event = 'GOAL'
group by team.name, 
         player.name
```

That will list, for every player, the player's team and number of goals.

Having that, you can wrap it in a "common table expression" (aka, a "CTE" or a "WITH clause") and use it as though it were a view in your database.  I.e., this...

```
with player_goals as (
    select team.name team_name, 
           player.name player_name,
           count(*) number_of_goals
    from       team
    inner join player on player.idteam = team.idteam
    inner join event on event.idplayer = player.idplayer
    where event.type_event = 'GOAL'
    group by team.name, 
             player.name)
select team_name,
       player_name,
       number_of_goals
from player_goals;
```

.. will return the same results as the first query, above.

Now, you can work to limit those results to just the top scoring players.  A windowing-function will help:

```
with player_goals as (
    select team.name team_name, 
           player.name player_name,
           count(*) number_of_goals
    from       team
    inner join player on player.idteam = team.idteam
    inner join event on event.idplayer = player.idplayer
    where event.type_event = 'GOAL'
    group by team.name, 
             player.name)
select team_name,
       player_name,
       number_of_goals,
       dense_rank() over ( partition by team_name order by number_of_goals desc) scoring_rank
from player_goals;
```

That `dense_rank()` expression tells Oracle to put all the rows in the result set into different groups ("windows"), one for each distinct `team_name`.  Then, within each window, sort each row (which is a player) in descending order by the number of goals and report each player's position in that sort.  E.g., the player(s) with the most goals will be ranked #1.

Important note: `dense_rank()` will player multiple players in position 1 if they are all tied for the most goals.  If that's not how you want to handle ties, clarify your question.

Unfortunately, you cannot use a windowing function in a `WHERE` clause.  If you could, we'd add

```
WHERE dense_rank() over ( partition by team_name order by number_of_goals desc) = 1
```

.. and be done.

Instead, we need to wrap what we've got in a 2nd common table expression and THEN apply a `WHERE` clause.

Here is the final query:

```
with player_goals as (
    select team.name team_name, 
           player.name player_name,
           count(*) number_of_goals
    from       team
    inner join player on player.idteam = team.idteam
    inner join event on event.idplayer = player.idplayer
    where event.type_event = 'GOAL'
    group by team.name, 
             player.name),
ranked_player_goals as (             
    select team_name,
           player_name,
           number_of_goals,
           dense_rank() over ( partition by team_name order by number_of_goals desc) scoring_rank
    from player_goals )
select team_name,
       player_name,
       number_of_goals
from   ranked_player_goals
where  scoring_rank = 1  -- top scorers only
;
```

#### Possible exam answer

If this is for a pencil-and-paper test and they haven't covered common table expressions or windowing functions, they might be looking for an answer like this:

```
select team.name, player.name, count(*) goals_scored
from   team, player, event
where  player.idteam = team.idteam
and    event.idplayer = player.idplayer
and    event.type_event = 'GOAL'
group by team.name, player.name, team.idteam, player.idplayer
having not exists ( SELECT 'player with more goals for team'
                    FROM   player p2, event e2
                    WHERE  p2.idteam = team.idteam
                    AND    e2.idplayer = p2.idplayer
                    AND    e2.type_event = 'GOAL'
                    GROUP BY p2.idplayer
                    HAVING count(distinct e2.idevent) > count(distinct event.idevent))
```

Comment: I should have added that this question is taken from an exam which is done by pen and paper (and I'm preparing for an exam in pen and paper), and the only indication is that 'goal' is the desired event. It's a single semester class and some of the things you use aren't familiar to me, but thanks a lot for the thorough answer!

Comment: @Gilberto I've updated my answer with something a little more basic that might be applicable to your exam.  It's still more than I'd want to write with pencil and paper though!

Comment: I forgot to respond but thank you so much for even giving me a simpler answer, it was really helpful on the real thing!

Answer (score 0):

Another option (read comments within code):

```
SQL> with
  2  -- Sample data; you already have that and don't need to type it
  3  team (idteam, name) as
  4    (select 1, 'Dinamo' from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'Hajduk' from dual
  6    ),
  7  player (idplayer, idteam, name) as
  8    (select 1, 1, 'Little' from dual union all
  9     select 2, 1, 'Foot'   from dual union all
 10     select 3, 2, 'Scott'  from dual
 11    ),
 12  event (idevent, idplayer, type_event) as
 13    -- at the end, Little scored 2 goals for Dinamo and
 14    --             Scott  scored 1 goal  for Hajduk --> those values should be the final result
 15    (select 1, 1, 'GOAL' from dual union all  --> Little scored once  for Dinamo
 16     select 2, 1, 'MISS' from dual union all
 17     select 3, 1, 'GOAL' from dual union all  --> Little scored twice for Dinamo
 18     select 4, 3, 'GOAL' from dual union all  --> Scott  scored once  for Hajduk
 19     select 5, 2, 'GOAL' from dual            --> Foot   scored once  for Dinamo
 20    ),
 21  -- code you need begins here
 22  temp as
 23    -- calculate number of goals per player and per team
 24    (select p.name player_name,
 25            t.name team_name,
 26            sum(decode(e.type_event, 'GOAL', 1, 0)) over
 27               (partition by p.name) goals_per_player
 28     from event e join player p on e.idplayer = p.idplayer
 29                  join team   t on t.idteam = p.idteam
 30    )
 31   select a.team_name,
 32          a.player_name,
 33          max(a.goals_per_player) goals
 34  From temp a
 35  group by a.team_name,
 36           a.player_name
 37  having max(a.goals_per_player) = (select max(b.goals_per_player)
 38                                    from temp b
 39                                    where b.team_name = a.team_name);

TEAM_N PLAYER      GOALS
------ ------ ----------
Dinamo Little          2
Hajduk Scott           1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can check this:

```
 select team.name team_name,
     player.name player_name   
 from team
 inner join player
     on team.idteam = player.idteam
 inner join event
     on player.idplayer = event.idplayer and event.type_event = 'GOAL'
 inner join (
           select idplayer, count(*) cnt from event
           group by idplayer
           where type_event = 'GOAL'
     ) evt
     on player.idplayer = evt.idplayer
group by team.idteam, player.idplayer
having max(evt.cnt) = count(*)
```